# How to select sql query for two table with multiple values in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my SQL Server database. The first is `bidder_interest_name` and second is `tender_type_subcat` . There have multiple value column `bidder_interest_subcategory`  in `bidder_interest_name` and `tender_type_subcategory` in `tender_type_subcat` tables.

Now I want to select the multiple values from both the tables for a particular subcategory and need to both table minimum matching value.

This is what I'm doing

What I have tried:

```
SELECT bi.bidder_interest_subcategory,tt.tender_type_subcategory 
FROM bidder_interest_list as bi,new_tender_two as tt 
WHERE bi.bidder_id=$bidder_id
```

Comment: use join query @illesh

Comment: Please post your tries

Comment: SELECT bi.bidder_interest_subcategory,tt.tender_type_subcategory FROM bidder_interest_list as bi,new_tender_two as tt WHERE bi.bidder_id=$bidder_id

Don't work

Comment: Do the tables relate (to one another) in some way? And note that SQL server is not MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT bi.bidder_id, bi.bidder_interest_subcategory,tt.tender_type_subcategory FROM bidder_interest_list as bi,new_tender_two as tt WHERE bi.bidder_id=$bidder_id;
```

Comment: yes 
but i have two table same value
i check this var_dump but output is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this :`SELECT bi.bidder_id=tt.tender_id, bi.bidder_interest_subcategory,tt.tender_type_subcategory FROM bidder_interest_list as bi,new_tender_two as tt WHERE bi.bidder_id=bidder_id;`